# Laravel Get and copy data from old Database to new Database with Foreign key

Tags: laravel, copy, foreign-keys, migrate

Hi i want to migrate data in table A from DB A into table A in DB B. I build laravel function to get and copy data from old DB to new DB.

In Table A     DB A

**ID Code Name CodeProduct**

1    A01   ABC   001

2    A02   BCD   002

3    A03   DDD

In Table A     DB B

**ID Code Name CodeProduct**

Both table have relationship with Foreign key with Table C by CodeProduct as FK.

My problem is i get error trying to get the ID, because CODEPRODUCT in OLD DB is NULL. If not null is okay no error.

i try to disable and enable FK like below code

DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;');

But get error SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='. (SQL: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;)

```html
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;');

$datas = codeloanpackage::get();

DB::connection('sqlsrv2')
            ->table('CodeLoanPackages')
            ->insert([
                'Id' => $data->id,
                "Code" => $data->code,
          "Name" => $data->name,
                "CodeProduct" => $data->CodeProducts->Id]);
        }

    // Enable foreign key checks!
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

Comment: Try [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/90ca43ca-cc05-4131-b06f-688400355c3c/set-foreign-key-checks-off-in-an-insert-script?forum=sqldatabaseengine) suggestion and if helps, feel free to write it as an answer. Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126598/how-to-correct-a-sql-server-syntax-error-setting-fk-contrainsts).

Answer (score 0):

You are using a MySQL raw query on a MSSQL database.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

and

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

The equivalent of it on MSSQL might be:

```
Alter Table myTable
    NOCHECK Constraint All
```

and

```
Alter Table myTable
    CHECK Constraint ALL
```

Edit (Better Option), use Eloquent

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

and

```
Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```